# C preprocessor assigning value to multiple types

Tags: c, string, macros, preprocessor, lexer

So im writing a Lexer and have come across a problem with my macro to generate a token (token is a struct with a value type (enum) and a value (union).

```
#define MAKE_TOKEN(token, tokenType, valueType, tokValue) \
    token.type=tokenType; \
    token.value.type=valueType; \
    switch(valueType){ \
        case VAL_NIL: break; \
        case VAL_BOOL: token.value.as.boolean=(bool)tokValue; break; \
        case VAL_NUMBER: token.value.as.number=(double)tokValue; break; \
        case VAL_STRING: token.value.as.string=(char*)tokValue; break; \
    }
```

This works if the tokValue is 5 for example (as 5 can be cast to a bool, double and char*), however, this doesn't compile as the compiler cannot cast a string to a double. This means that this macro cannot be used when the value type is VAL_STRING, how do I fix this?

Comment: I did not understand your explanation. Can you add more info and/or explain it better? there is no `double` in your example.

Comment: Why is this a macro and not a function?

Answer (score 1):

You can't make it work as a macro because a macro in the C preprocessor merely performs string interpolation, so the troublesome line does:

```
    case VAL_NUMBER: token.value.as.number=(double)"some_string"; break;
```

Just use a function instead. There's no apparent reason for this fragment to be a macro.

```
void MAKE_TOKEN(struct token *token, enum token_type tokenType, enum value_type valueType, void *tokValue) {
    token->type = tokenType;
    token->value.type = valueType; 
    switch(valueType){
    case VAL_NIL:
        break;
    case VAL_BOOL:
        token->value.as.boolean = *(bool*)tokValue;
        break;
    case VAL_NUMBER:
        token->value.as.number = *(double*)tokValue;
        break;

    case VAL_STRING:
        token->value.as.string = *(char**)tokValue;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `token->` instead of `token.`